# Missing Order Items in New Created Email Template

Tags: magento, module, email-templates

I've created a new observer to send after an order is payed, an email to my supplier to produce goods that I need.
So I receive the email right with all data except the order item list. Also data are formatted different from the standard order_new.html. The layout is wrong, seem a missing css style problem.

Before that, I hadthe html file inside template/email/sales folder like the order_new.html and i was receiving only a blank mail. So I put the file in template/email and now I receive that worng layout and without order items.

I don't understand why. Can you help me to solve this problem?

So this is my Oberser.php code

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model_Observer
{
 public function notifyOwnerEvent($observer)
{

    // parameters you can get from the $observer parameter:
    // array(’payment’ ? $this, ‘invoice’ ? $invoice)

    $payment = $observer->getPayment();
    $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();

    // derivative data
    $order = $invoice->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order

    $ownerEmail = 'xxxx6@gmail.com';
    $Subject = 'Oggetto :';
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->loadDefault('order_copy_for_supplier');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Prova di Ordine Confermato dopo pagamento');
    $emailTemplate->setToName($senderName);
    $emailTemplate->setToEmail($ownerEmail);
    $emailTemplate->setBody($processedTemplate);
    $emailTemplate->setSubject($Subject);
    $emailTemplate->setFromEmail($senderEmail);
    $emailTemplate->setFromName($senderName);
     $emailTemplate->setType('html');

    // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
    $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

   //Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    //Getting the Store General E-Mail.
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;
    $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
    $emailTemplateVariables['order_data'] = $order->getCreatedAtFormated();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);   
    $emailTemplate->send($ownerEmail, $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);

    //$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
    //$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email')
    //->setToName($senderName)
    //->setToEmail($ownerEmail)
    //->setBody($processedTemplate)
    //->setSubject($Subject)
     //->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
     //->setFromName($senderName)
     //->setType('html');
     //try{
     //Confimation E-Mail Send
     //$mail->send();
     //}
     //catch(Exception $error)
     //{
     //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
     //return false;
     //}


    return $this;  // always return $this.
}




}
```

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <notifyowner>
            <class>Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model</class>
        </notifyowner>
    </models>          
    <events>
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <notifyOwnerEvent>
                            <class>notifyowner/observer</class>
                            <method>notifyOwnerEvent</method>
                    </notifyOwnerEvent>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay >     
    </events>
    <template>
        <email>
            <order_copy_for_supplier module="Electricjesus_Notifyowner">
                <label>Nuovo Ordine Per Fornitore</label>
                <file>order_copy_for_supplier.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </order_copy_for_supplier>
        </email>
    </template>
 </global>
```

And this is my template:

```
<!--@subject {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Nuovo Ordine Per        Fornitore # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()":"Customer Name",
"var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')":"Billing Address",
"var payment_html":"Payment Details",
"var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order":"Order Items Grid",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note"}
@-->
<!--@styles
@-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
                        <h1>Nuovo ordine da produrre{{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
                        <p>Gentile Fornitore, vi preghiamo di mettere in produzione il seguente ordine. </p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="store-info">
                        <h4>Info da inviare a </h4>
                        <p>
                            {{depend store_phone}}
                            <b>Chiamaci:</b>
                            <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_hours}}
                            <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_email}}
                            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                            {{/depend}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-details">
            <h3>Ns. Ordine N. <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
            <p>Effettuato il {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Fattura a:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Spedizione a:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Metodo di spedizione:</h6>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Metodo di pagamento:</h6>
                        {{var payment_html}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    {{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Comment: To clarify, please tell us what layout you are getting and what layout you are expecting.

Comment: It's difficult to explain, I copied the order new layout, so the standard mail of the confirmation order with item list. It has some colored blocks with text inside. Instead in the copy layout from my observer I obtain a only text mail with all information and Item are missing. I don't see the colored blocks.

Comment: The path to your CSS is likely wrong since you moved the file from another location. Since the old path was "template/email/sales" and the new path is "template/email", your CSS path will need "sales/" added to it. That should take care of the coloring. I'm not sure what's keeping the data from showing up.

Comment: I've added in the config.xml file the right directory for the original template, so `<file>sales/order_copy_for_supplier.html</file>` but the result is the same.

Comment: someone can help me to understand? My css is missing and order item also..